# Weight of minimum spanning tree of G and T

Tags: algorithms, graphs, weighted-graphs

[image]We have undirected weighted connective graph $G=(V,E)$, We also have a minimum spanning tree $T$ of $G$.
Let $v$ be some vertex.
We have new graphs, $G'$ and $T'$.
$G'$ and $T'$ are same $G$ and $T$, except the extra node $v$ witch is connected (with new weighted edges) to the same nodes in both graphs.
I need to prove that $G'$ MSP has the same weight as $T'$ MSP.
I was thinking about using kruskal or prim algorithm to show that Given a MSP of $T'$, We can use kruskal or prim on $G'$ to find it, with no results.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't understand the construction of $G'$ and $T'$

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. $G' = ( V ⋃ $ {$v$} $ , E' )$. $E' = E ⋃ $ { $(u,v) | u ∈ V $}. $T'$ is defined similarly.

Comment: So the new node $v$ is connected to all nodes in the original graph?

Comment: Not necessarily, It can be connected to any node in $G$ and $T$.

Comment: Added a small example.

Comment: Hint, any MSP can be obtained by a series of deletions, each of which deletes one of the heaviest edges on a cycle.

Comment: ok I think I got this.  we can show that the series of deletions leading from G to T, would create T' out of G', afterward we can continue with the blue rule. thanks.